# Is there a way I can compute all this possible paths and store them?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix and each of its columns represents a sequence of points, to be more specific:

```
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 6     6     6     6     5     5     5     5     4     4     4     4     3     3     3     3     2     2     2     2
 5     4     3     2     6     4     3     2     6     5     3     2     6     5     4     2     6     5     4     3
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     3     2     2     2     3     2     2     2     3     2     2     2     4     3     3     3     4
 3     3     4     4     3     3     4     4     3     3     5     5     4     4     5     5     4     4     5     5
 4     5     5     5     4     6     6     6     5     6     6     6     5     6     6     6     5     6     6     6
```

1 stands for point number one, 2 stands for point number two, and so on.
So as said above, every column represent a different configuration of a set of point (x and y coordinates).

If the set of points is:

```
 (1,9)
 (2,5)
 (3,7)
 (4,2)
 (2,1)
 (2,3)
```

then one possible path, according to the first column is:

```
 (1,9)
 (2,3)
 (2,1)
 (1,9)
 (2,5)
 (3,7)
 (4,2)
```

Is there a way I can compute all this possible configurations and store them?

When I first approached this problem I didn't know about graph theory, that's why so far I am not using it.

Comment: Why do you have point 1 duplicated in each column? Are you simply looking for the permutations of `1:6`, or is there some connectivity information that determines what point can follow a given point?

Comment: could you present them as connectivity matrix? I have a solution how to find and save all possible Hamiltonian pathways

Comment: Beaker, the 1 represent the starting point, and I wanted to connect at ost points in the same paths, that's why the repetition.
Zlon, problably it is possible, I think it is used with graphs as well, can I see your solution please?

Comment: @user158013 What does "at **ost** points" mean? Again, why is the duplicate `1` there in your matrix? It doesn't appear in your example path. Are you just ignoring it? Is `1` *always* the starting point, or did you just not show the others?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the logics behind the fouth row of your sequence matrix. It's filled with `1` but they seem to be completely ignored by your example. Respecting your example, given the points:

```
(1,9) (2,5) (3,7) (4,2) (2,1) (2,3)
```

and the first column sequence:

```
1 6 5 1 2 3 4
```

the output should be:

```
(1,9) (2,3) (2,1) (1,9) (2,5) (3,7) (4,2)
```

and not:

```
(1,9) (2,3) (2,1) (2,5) (3,7) (4,2)
```

Since I don't know how your scripts should work and how I should deal with the fourth row, I implemented a code that ignore that logic, producing the result that seems the most obvious to me:

```
seq = [
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2
  5 4 3 2 6 4 3 2 6 5 3 2 6 5 4 2 6 5 4 3
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  2 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 4 3 3 3 4
  3 3 4 4 3 3 4 4 3 3 5 5 4 4 5 5 4 4 5 5
  4 5 5 5 4 6 6 6 5 6 6 6 5 6 6 6 5 6 6 6
];

pts = {
  [1 9]
  [2 5]
  [3 7]
  [4 2]
  [2 1]
  [2 3]
};

paths = pts(seq);
```

Then, in order to access the paths you can to, for example:

```
for i = 1:size(paths,2)
    disp(cell2mat(paths(:,i)))
end
```

or:

```
paths = cell2mat(paths);

for i = 1:2:(size(paths,2) / 2)
    x = paths(:,i);
    y = paths(:,i+1);
    disp([x y]);
end
```

Comment: Yeah, my script produces exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I also need to get access to the points and I can with cell2mat(), do you know more elegant solutions?
(Thanks!)

Comment: What is not elegant enough in cell2mat? You double the number of rows, so you will have x / y couples every 2 columns.

Comment: That's true, I just didn't use matlab in a while.
One last question if I can, can I access all the points in a loop?